# How to export all values of lists to csv on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

```
list_1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']
list_2 = ['n1','n2','n3','n4','n5','n6','n7','n8','n9','n10']
list_3 = ['o1','o2','o3','o4','o5','o6','o7','o8','o9','o10']

cols = zip(list_1,list_2,list_3)

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)

    thewriter.writerow(['list_1','list_2','list_3'])
    for col in cols:
       thewriter.writerow(col)
```

## Output

```
list1   list2   list3
  1      n1      o1
  2      n2      o2
  3      n3      o3
  4      n4      o4
  5      n5      o5
  6      n6      o6
  7      n7      o7
  8      n8      o8
```

## Expected Output

```
list1   list2   list3
  1      n1      o1
  2      n2      o2
  3      n3      o3
  4      n4      o4
  5      n5      o5
  6      n6      o6
  7      n7      o7
  8      n8      o8
         n9      o9
         n10     o10
```

I have 3 lists, `list_1` has 8 items, `list_2` has 10 items and `list_3` also have 10 items,

but when I write the lists to csv, `list_2` and `list_3` columns do not show the last 2 items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the default behavior of `zip`: truncate to the length of the shortest iterable. You can use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead:

- Import it first:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
```

- Then replace the line where you assign `cols` with:

```
cols = zip_longest(list_1,list_2,list_3, fillvalue="")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can see this [Link](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and this other [link](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/)

> Passing Arguments of Unequal Length When you’re working with the
>   Python `zip()` function, it’s important to pay attention to the length
>   of your iterables. It’s possible that the iterables you pass in as
>   arguments aren’t the same length.
>
> In these cases, the number of elements that `zip()` puts out will be
>   **equal to the length of the shortest iterable**. **The remaining elements
>   in any longer iterables will be totally ignored by** `zip()`

In your case, you will get int cuted to the 8th value (the sortest list).

**EDIT**

You can use this info [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

itertools.zip_longest(*iterables[, fillvalue])

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>   If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in
>   with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is
>   exhausted. Equivalent to:

```
def zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=None):
     # zip_longest('ABCD', 'xy', fillvalue='-') --> Ax By C- D-
     def sentinel(counter = ([fillvalue]*(len(args)-1)).pop):
         yield counter()         # yields the fillvalue, or raises IndexError
     fillers = repeat(fillvalue)
     iters = [chain(it, sentinel(), fillers) for it in args]
     try:
         for tup in zip(*iters):
            yield tup
     except IndexError:
         pass
```

> If one of the iterables is potentially infinite, then the
>   zip_longest() function should be wrapped with something that limits
>   the number of calls (for example islice() or takewhile()). If not
>   specified, fillvalue defaults to None.

Example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

l_1 = [1, 2, 3]
l_2 = [1, 2]

combinated = list(zip_longest(l_1, l_2, fillvalue="_"))

print(combinated)  # [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, '_')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.